# Why can't I access Apache webserver externally?

Tags: apache, server, port, external

I have a windows server with Apache installed through port 93. Locally it works fine but when I try to access it on a external computer the connection says 'Can't connect: It takes too long' everytime. I have added the port at inbound connections in my firewall and changed the 'listen' line in httpd.conf to : 'Listen 93'.

I have checked around for a while but nothing seems to be solving.
Someone who can help me further?

Comment: Still looks like a firewall issue. Try to `telnet` to this port or check with `nmap`. Also, check Apache logs, just in case.

Comment: @ElvisPlesky I have checked the Apache logs, but nothing gets added whenever I request the webpage on the remote computer. With regard to the telnet, when I try the command: telnet http://145.24.xxx.yyy:93/ it says me this (translated): 'Cant make connection with the host, on port 23. Making connection is failed'.

Comment: Record absence in logs proves that it is a network issue. Is the server behind the NAT? Is port forwarding set up correctly? Is there an intermediate firewall?

Comment: @ElvisPlesky could you please explain shortly how to get to know these things in a beginners language?